# How to make a product not visible in storefront

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, custom-options, magento-2.2.5

Current Magento Version: Magento EE 2.2.5

I have created a product in admin panel

I need that product not to display in storefront but I should be able to place an order for that product through API.

If I disable that product, it will not show up in storefront and also I will not be able to place order for that product through API too.

Is there any way to make a product only accessible only through API?

Thanks,
Sahana

Answer (score 0):

If the product is still allowed to be accessed by it's direct URL, then you can just set the visibility of the product to "Not visible individually".

Then the product can still be ordered by the API, but it also has a public page. But: the product will not appear in listings and search results. I'm not sure about `sitemap.xml` however (or any other feed that you might be generating), so you might want to double-check that one.

If you don't want the product to be accessible by it's URL you might have to perform some other magic. If that's the case, please update your question.

Comment: When i set product to 'Not visible individually' it will not be accessible using direct link.